# Using regex how do you extract a number following a string? (the output should be just the number)

Tags: regex

How would I do this using regex?

Example input: `This is a sentence 1234 with a bunch of other stuff`.

output: `1234`.

I know if I do this: `(?<=This is a sentence).\d\d\d\d` I can replace the four digit number with anything. But I want to do exactly the opposite: I want to replace everything except the match with something, in this case with nothing (ie "").

Comment: (?<=This is a sentence).\d\d\d\d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a replace all with

```
\D
```

as regex and `""` being what to replace the matched terms with.

`\d` means a numeric character.

`\D` means a non-numeric character.

EDIT: Since you seem to need a very literal regex... I'd run two replaces, the first to remove everything before the number, and the second to remove everything after the number.

```
first = replace("This is a sentence 1234 with a bunch of other stuff",".*[Tt]his is a sentence (?=1234)","")
second = replace(first,"\D+.*","")
```

Comment: @Arash What language are you using?

Comment: I'm not using a standard language. It's a specific environment that I'm using. All I have access to is the replace command like this: replace(original_text,regex_expression,replace_expression)

Answer (score 1):

We need to replace all the characters with empty`""`

Sample code:

```
var="This is a sentence 1234 with a bunch of other stuff";
intVar = var.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z ]", "");
```

the output will be 1234

Comment: Thanks, but this will give me all the non letters. I just want to have the 1234 between the specified sentence. Your method will not work for example for "123456 this is a sentence 1234 with other stuff %%% and some more numbers that I don't want 1234566"

Answer (score 0):

You match a sequence of digits with `\d+` or `[0-9]+`.

Comment: Yes but I want to replace everything except the four digit number with nothing so that at the end the replaced text is "1234"